# How can a configuration file in C# be optional?

Tags: c#, configuration, configuration-files

I hope someone can help me in the right direction:

### The problem

I have a set of tests that take a url as a parameter. I'd like that url to be easily configurable by other developers, so they can direct the tests to a server of their choosing. But this developer-specific setting should not be committed, the library is also run in a CI loop and **it** provides the url via an environment variable.

I would let developers also just set the environment variable, but it doesn't appear to be possible to do anything with environment vars from within Visual Studio. So I wanted to make it so if a configuration file exists it'll be used as the url variable.

But I can't find a way to make an optional config file in C#. I've already tried a couple solutions:

#### Application settings / app.config

[image: Application settings]

I've tried application settings, but they don't allow user-settings that can be easily edited for a developer. If there's a way to have the settings look at a `user.config` file as an (optional) sibling to the `app.config` file that might work, but I don't see a way to make it do that.

#### Rolling my own `settings.json`

I made an attempt at parsing a json file, though I managed to get the basics working of only loading the file if it exists I had to resort to some unholy hacks to get this `settings.json` file put alongside the built assemblies:

[image: Unholy hacks]

(The `_ignore.txt` file is a hack to make sure the pre-build event fires, and.. I'll let the event speak for itself. This kind of manual copying-around certainly doesn't fill me with a lot of confidence!

### Ze question

How would you approach this problem? I feel I could cook this up easily in Python or Javascript, but I'm new to C# and despite many hours of struggling haven't found what feels like a sensible solution. I "just" wanted to let developers decide on the url without them ending up with a modified file they have to remember not to check in, but it's turned out to be a lot more problematic than I thought it'd be. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You are expected to provide a way for the user to easily edit any user.config setting.  An Options menu item is boilerplate.  You don't *have* to do it that way, your alternative is no different from having the settings' Scope to "Application".  Since the only way they can edit the .config or .json file is by acquiring UAC elevation.

Comment: You're referring to using "application settings", correct? I "just" have a set of unit tests so there is no main app to add menu items to. I'm hoping the use case of allowing a developer to set/alter a value that redirects the tests is not one that invokes UAC and similar application-level concerns.

Comment: When you say "user.config" then you are indeed talking about application settings.  And no, they are not useful in a unit test since application settings are married to the EXE.  A simple xml or json file stored in a predictable location should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, my solution would be to put the values in the 'Command line arguments' box in the 'debug' tab in your project's properties (the option below the 'Build events' tab in your screenshot).

You could add something like:

```
"www.developerwebsite.com" "C:/developer folder"
```

and get those values using:

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var url = args[1];
MessageBox.Show(url);
```

(NB: args[0] is the name of the .exe)

Bear in mind though, that method could be a security risk, because any user would be able to pass those values into your application.

Comment: Thank you for reading between the lines and present an alternate solution. I like the idea, but unfortunately it looks like command line arguments are not picked up when running tests (we run them through ReSharper's test runner and it uses its own set of command line arguments).

Comment: You are running unit tests, correct? Well, normally I put tests into a separate project in the solution. This allows you to set the app.config values to what the tests need without affecting what gets published. Is that the kind of code structure you have?

Comment: Correct. When I tried app.config I couldn't find a way to allow a developer to overwrite those values without ending up w. an altered file they have to remember not to check in.

Comment: Hmmm...not sure what else to suggest. I'll have another thunk.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972903/different-configuration-settings-per-developer-for-c-sharp-class-library