# Point connectionstring in dbml to app.config

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Can I just point the connection string in `Dbml.designer.cs` to the connectionstring in the `app.conf`? I wrote the code below which it successfully point to the `app.config`.

```
public leDataContext() : 
    base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leConnString"].ToString(), mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

However whenever i modify or add a table into the dbml, it will start to auto replace that code into this

```
 public leDataContext() : 
            base("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\\My Projects\\App_Data\\le.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

I have expanded the "Connection" option. Set "Application Settings" to False

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Don't modify `Dbml.designer.cs` file manually, because it will be rewritten when you edit/add a table etc. as you said. Instead of this set the `Connection` property for the `.dbml` designer file to `None` and add a partial class with parameterless constructor:

```
public partial class leDataContext
{ 
   public leDataContext() : 
       base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leConnString"].ToString())
    {
        OnCreated();
    }    
}
```

Comment: i have make the connnection to be empty and add new constructor together with other constructors. But it still change to `base("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFile..` public leDataContext() :
        base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leConnString"].ToString())
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public leDataContext(string connection) :
        base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public leDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) :
        base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

Comment: @belinq: your should add a new file and define parameterless constructor there (in a partial class). In this case this constructor won't be overwritten. As far as I understand you put this constructor into the `dbml.designer.cs` file - this is the problem.

Comment: Note: in Visual Studio 2013 we don't have that connection property so I just removed the connection node from the dbml xml file directly.

Comment: It seems you must also inherit from System.Data.Linq.DataContext or there is no OnCreated() base method to call.

Answer (score 55):

This is more like an extension to @Alex's answer.

**Step 1** : Set the connection property of your .dbml file to “none”.

[image]

**Step 2 :** Create a new separate partial class with the same name as that of the existing partial class for the .dbml file. And set the connectionString property by using the parameterless constructor.

```
public partial class DataClassesDataContext
{
  public DataClassesDataContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev-connString"].ConnectionString)
  {
    OnCreated();
  }
}
```

**Step 3 :** Almost Done ! Lastly you need to define your connectionString in your app.config file, as shown below.

```
<connectionStrings>

  <add
  name="Dev-connString"
  connectionString="Data Source=yasser-home;Initial Catalog=pp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=gogole"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

You can now easily change the connectionString from the app.config file without having to re-compile your code, which would be the case otherwise.

**Why did I create a seperate partial class ? Can’t I edit the existing Dbml.designer.cs file ?**

Don’t modify Dbml.designer.cs file manually, because it will be rewritten when you add/edit/delete a table, stored proc etc.

Comment: thanks. and you set the connection property to none, because otherwise it defines it's own constructor

Comment: Small addition; to set the connectionstring to none you need to open the dbml so it shows the model schema on the left. Then rightclick inside the schema and click properties.

Comment: This should be the answer as it includes further instructions.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I found this only worked when I declared the class to be within the MyProject.Content namespace. (Where MyProject is obviously the base namespace of your own project.)