# Cannot open user default database. Login failed.for user

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I built a windows forms application  project and connected a SQL Server database using Linq-to-SQL. Everything worked properly until this error appeared :

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
>   Login failed for user

Connection string is:

```
 Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ShippingDocumentDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

Did not find any solution for that.

Comment: Did you verify your `connection string` contains all the necessary parameters?

Comment: Can you post your connection string in your question?

Comment: I am quite a beginner, everything worked correctly I even managed to insert data  So I guess everything is fine regard to connection string..

Comment: @even11. It sounds like your file is locked and can't be attached to your user instance of SQL Server. Do you have the file attached to the main SQL instance in SQL Server Management Studio when you get the error? See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the default database for the current user account has been removed, or permissions to that database have been removed for the user you are looking at.

- Has this user been able to login before?
- Can you connect to SQL server as a different user and find out what that user's default database is?

As an example, try runnning this against sql server when logged in to SQL Server Management Studio (works on SQL Server 2005 onwards):

```
SELECT name, default_database_name
FROM sys.server_principals
```

Check the value in the second column for the user in question, and then see if that database exists and the user has permission to it.

**EDIT**. We now know from your connection string that you are using a [user instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx). YOu need to check that the database file is available. It may be attached to SQL Server's main instance, for example, which would mean the file is in use and can't be attached to the user instance. Try making a copy of the database file using windows explorer and put the name of that file copy into the [`AttachDbFilename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sqlexpuser_topic2) parameter - that may show that this is the case.

Comment: I was logged in before with the same user.

Comment: The user default database in SQL server is master , and I successfully connect to all database using the same user

Comment: @even11. Answer updated with new thoughts given your new info in your question.

Comment: I create a new copy of my database, but how and where can I set the connection string ?

Comment: Where did you get the connection string from that you copied into your answer: check to see if it is in your app.config and you can change it there? (It is hard to know without knowing how you have set your application up - do you have a dbml file, for instance)?

Comment: I opened the data source configuration wizard and copied from there,

Comment: @even11. Check your app.config to see if you can change it in there (see the [MSDN reference for saving the connection to app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dd7z6t(v=vs.80).aspx#saveconnectionstringtotheapplicationconfigurationfile) and [editing the connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171889(v=vs.80).aspx)).

Comment: @even11. In that case your conenction string _should be in your app.config_ Can you please confirm if it is or not? (see this question for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139043/point-connectionstring-in-dbml-to-app-config)

Comment: I did change the connection string and it is also changed in the app.config,and now its works when I debugging, but why cant I get access the database through the database explorer window ?

Comment: @even11. You may need to ask that in a new question - comments are not the right place to have a long discussion.

Comment: Andy, you realy helped me I learned a lot from you and need more time for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define this user for your specific database;

Answer (score -1):

For a SQL Server Connection string, it should be in this format:

```
 SERVER=[SVRNAME\INSTANCENAME];USER=[USERID];PWD=[PASSWORD];DATABASE=[DATABASENAME]
```

Comment: The connection string built by wizard , Do you think it should be modified ?

Comment: The connection string is valid, it is just for a [user instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx) that are often [used in visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504(v=vs.80).aspx) instead of a server instance. The connection string format you have posted will only work if the database is permanently attached to the main server instance. You should make this clear in your answer.

Comment: @AndyBrown. I do not have enough reputation, Sorry.