# LINQ to SQL Database Server Override

Tags: linq-to-sql

Writing a VB .NET windows application.

We have a LAN network of 3 SQL servers, each with the identical database tables on each.
The only difference is the data which applies to 3 different locations of users.

Trying to use LINQ to SQL, which I'm fairly new at, hence this question.

I've created a .dbml file and connected to one of the servers. I then dragged
several tables to it. The connections string is stored in project settings.
I then created two more connection strings for the other servers.

My question is, can I somehow override the data context connection in code to connect
to the other 2 servers based on a variable condition?

Here is the code I have so far, but my "override" does not seem to work. When I
debug the data context variable it shows the original connection from design time?

'' create LINQ datacontext connection to SQL server based on location
    Public dbContext As New DataBaseDataContext()

```
Select Case My.Settings.Location
            Case "Bowling Green"
                dbContext.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.bg_prodConnectionString

                Dim query = From emp In dbContext.employees _
                          Select emp

                For Each emp In query

                    MsgBox(emp.name.ToString())

                Next

            Case "Delphos"
                Dim DelphosContext As New DataBaseDataContext(My.Settings.delphos_prodConnectionString)
                'DelphosContext.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.delphos_prodConnectionString

                Dim query = From emp In DelphosContext.employees _
                            Select emp _
                            Where emp.employee_id = "0028"
                            Order By emp.name

                For Each emp In query

                    MsgBox(emp.name.ToString())

                Next

            Case "Tiffin"

                dbContext.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.tiffin_prodConnectionString

        End Select
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good solution that involves a few steps to setup but nothing
difficult. Please keep in mind that the servers and databases need to be identical
in schema, but I have a work a round see step 5.

1) create your DBML file and drag some tables to it. Mine is called "DataBase".
   You must now do some things on the data context properties of the DBML, plus:
   A) expand the connection property and clear out any connection string you see there.
   B) set application settings to false, so the project doesn't use any.
   C) remove any connection strings (set to none) that DBML auto creates from the DBML
   (I did this to make sure the settings file connection did not override my run time code)

2) Add your static SQL server connections to the app.config file like so.

```
<pre>
 <appSettings>
     <add key="BGConnectionString" value="bg_prodConnectionString"/>
     <add key="DelphosConnectionString" value="delphos_prodConnectionString"/>
     <add key="TiffinConnectionString" value="tiffin_prodConnectionString"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="bg_prodConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tmd-bg-sql;Initial Catalog=bg_prod;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="delphos_prodConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tmd-d2-sql;Initial Catalog=delphos2_prod;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="tiffin_prodConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tmd-tiffin-sql;Initial Catalog=tiffin_prod;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<code>
```

3)The idea here is to use ONE and only ONE data context through out ALL forms and
classes etc. of the application, so setup a Public variable. What we want to do is
give it an initial connection string that can be changed later.

```
<pre>
Public dc As New DataBaseDataContext("Data Source=tmd-bg-sql;Initial Catalog=bg_prod;Persist   Security Info=True;User ID=sa")
<code>
```

4) Use a variable of some kind to determine how your server/database "override" works.
I used a My.settings string variable called "location" setup in MyProject (VB). This is
saved in another form that is called at startup.

Now do the "override" **one time** (program startup form or module) and allow it to be used everywhere globally.

```
<pre>
  ' save this first settings first before executing this code block
  Select Case My.Settings.Location
            Case "Bowling Green"
                ' Read the ConnectionStrings from the config file
                Dim ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BGConnectionString")).ConnectionString
                dc.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString

                Try

                    Dim query = From emp In dc.employees _
                       Select emp.name, emp.employee_id _
                       Order By name

                    For Each emp In query

                        MsgBox("BG")
                        Exit For
                        'MsgBox(emp.name)

                    Next

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)

                End Try

            Case "Delphos"
                ' Read the ConnectionStrings from the config file
                Dim ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DelphosConnectionString")).ConnectionString
                dc.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString

                Dim query = From emp In dc.employees _
                            Select emp.name, emp.employee_id _
                            Order By name

                For Each emp In query

                    MsgBox("Delphos")
                    Exit For

                Next

            Case "Tiffin"
                ' Read the ConnectionStrings from the config file
                Dim ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TiffinConnectionString")).ConnectionString
                dc.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString

                Dim query = From emp In dc.employees _
                           Select emp.name, emp.employee_id _
                           Order By name

                For Each emp In query

                    MsgBox("Tiffin")
                    Exit For

                Next

        End Select

' reference the dc context connection from another form or class
' instance the MDI form to get the public connection
        Dim MDI As New MDIParent

 Dim query = From emp In MDI.dc.employees _
                          Select emp.name, emp.employee_id _
                          Order By name

                For Each emp In query

                    MsgBox("Tiffin")
                    Exit For

                Next

<code>
```

5) I can now connect and access 3 different SQL servers, with 3 different databases
using minimal code. Now, my databases are almost identical, but here is one trick if they aren't.
I happen to have an extra field column in my employees table. I dragged that one into the
DBML. As long as you specify the columns names in your LINQ query that you want you will avoid
an exception error when the query "overrides" to another database.

I cant take all the credit for this.
I found other pieces of code from here.
[Click for Code](http://weblogs.asp.net/guybarrette/archive/2008/07/23/linq-to-sql-dynamic-mapping.aspx)

And here:

[And click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139043/point-connectionstring-in-dbml-to-app-config)